# Azure Functions server error metric logs not found

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an isolated Azure function app with metric alert for server errors. The alert gets triggered at times when I publish the Azure functions. However, I couldn't find any logs related to the server error in the application insights under the tables 'traces' or 'exceptions'. How do I get server error metrics log ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I deployed one function app and created HTTP 500 errors for logging:-

[image]

You can validate if Application Insights in enabled for your function app by checking if APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY Setting is present in the Configuration tab of your function App like below:-

[image]

I went to the Metric section and was able to retrieve all the metrics graphs of HTTP server errors like below:-

I changed the scope from my Azure Function app to  **application insights**  connected to the Function app to get the HTTP metrics like below:-

[image]

1. Get metrics for Server Exceptions :-

[image]

2. Get metrics for HTTP failed and successful requests:-

[image]

[image]

Validated the same in the Function Monitoring tab like below:-

[image]

3. You can find metrics related to server below:-

[image]

[image]

Additionally, You can inspect the logs in the  **requests table**  by clicking on the Log tab in the left of your Function app and check for the HTTP Server logs.

Click on Run query in Application insights:-

[image]

Run the query and inspect requests table:-

[image]

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    id,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'silixonfunctionapp' and operation_Name =~ 'HttpTrigger1'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

You can also check other logs from the left:-

[image]

If the metrics is still not populating the logs you can check the  **Performance tab**  in your Application Insights workspace like below:-

[image]

Click on the HTTP trigger from above and an end to end transaction of your Azure Function app will open for inspection like below:-

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Configure monitoring for Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2)

Comment: I didn't ask for how to create alerts. It is about missing logs. Please delete your answer.